# Pandas: Storing dataframe in more than one json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a very big pandas dataframe like this:

```
X1      | X2      | y
[1,2,3] | [1,5,6] | 2.5
[3,2,1] | [2,1,3] | 3
...
```

As the dataframe is very large, I want to store it in more than one file containing part of the dataframe(lets say 3 files having 33% of dataframe each). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could store it to HD5-format or a database too ( for speed gains).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, split it:

```
split1 = len(df) // 3
split2 = split1 * 2

df.iloc[:split1].to_json(...)
df.iloc[split1:split2].to_json(...)
df.iloc[split2:].to_json(...)
```

It might instead make sense to write one column per file:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].to_json(...)
```